# Validation for 3 instances

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put a validation for when you get the same date, with the same time and same venue, it will not insert in the database. It will only insert in the database if 1 instance will return false.

```
$res_date = $_POST['res_date'];
$res_venue = $_POST['res_venue'];
$res_dur = $_POST['res_duration'];

$qryjay = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE res_date='$res_date' AND res_dur = '$res_dur' AND res_venue = '$res_venue'");        
if ((mysql_num_rows($qryjay) == $res_date) && ($qryjay == $res_dur) && ($qryjay) == $res_venue){
echo "<script language=javascript>alert('".$res_venue." is not available on ".$res_dur." on ".$res_date."!')</script>";
}
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: OK, good luck with that task.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` will have the no. of affected rows how it will equal to date or time common sense

Comment: your if statement is not at all proper, plus SQL INJECTION, will give bad effect to your code and also u :)

Comment: do i really have to get those reply, or can i newbie at php get a help? D:

Comment: Help with what exactly? You haven't asked any *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix your code like this:

```
<?
$res_date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['res_date']);
$res_venue = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['res_venue']);
$res_dur = mysql_real_escape_string$_POST['res_duration']);

$qryjay = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as countNbr FROM tbl_reservation WHERE res_date='".$res_date."' AND res_dur = '".$res_dur."' AND res_venue = '".$res_venue."'");        
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryjay);
if ($result['countNbr'] > 0)){
    echo "<script language=javascript>alert('".$res_venue." is not available on ".$res_dur." on ".$res_date."!')</script>";
}
?>
```